# How to get referrer data in a Custom Authorize Attribute in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-attributes

How to get referrer data like the IP address and the apiKey in a Custom Authorize Attribute in an ASP.NET.
In the code below I'd like to get the data mentioned above:

```
  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class Auth : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var cnt = HttpContext.Current;
        return false;
    }
}
```

In HttpContext.Current I can get the url referrer but that doesn't have all the data I need.

Please let me know if this question is unclear or incomplete.

**Update**:
For those who need to know, the code below shows how.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class Auth : AuthorizeAttribute
{

    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var cnt = HttpContext.Current;
        int id = Int32.Parse(cnt.Request.Params["id"]);
        string apiKey = cnt.Request.Params["apiKey"];
        string IP = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        return true;
    }
}
```